# Proving a quotient ring is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $f(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 15x - 6 \in Q[x]$ and $I = (f) \in Q[x]$.

Prove that the quotient ring $Q[x]/I$ is a field.

Since $Q[x]$ is a PID it suffices to show that $f$ is irreducible, right?
how one can prove that?

Comment: Eisenstein criterion with $p=3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), $f$ has no rational roots. Since the degree is $3$, it follows that $f$ is irreducible. Eisenstein criterion with $p=3$ is another way to show this.